# How to solve this equation in general $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0 ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example if you have $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then solution given by formula $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Is there formula like this for $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0 ?$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such formula exists, and it is called the [cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), however it isn't nice looking: $$\begin{align}x &= \sqrt[\displaystyle3\,]{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \dfrac{bc}{6a^2} - \dfrac{d}{2a}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{3a}-\dfrac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}}\\
& + \sqrt[\displaystyle3\,]{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right) - \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{3a}-\dfrac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}} - \dfrac{b}{3a}.\end{align}$$
It can be made more simple, as suggested by [*@SenexÆgyptiParvi*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/94874/senex-%c3%86gypti-parvi), if you let $P=3ac-b^2$ and $Q=27a^2d-9abc+2b^3$, then $$x={{{\sqrt[3]{4\left(-Q+\sqrt{4P^3+Q^2}\right)}}+{\sqrt[3]{4\left(-Q-\sqrt{4P^3‌​+Q^2}\right)}}-{2ab}}\over{6a}}.$$

Comment: I broke it into two lines, which confirmed my suspicion that your two cube roots are identical. Should there be a minus sign in front of one of the square roots inside?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: A bit prettier, perhaps: If $P=3ac-b^2$ and $Q=27a^2d-9abc+2b^3$, then 
$x={{{\sqrt[3]{4\left(-Q+\sqrt{4P^3+Q^2}\right)}}+{\sqrt[3]{4\left(-Q-\sqrt{4P^3+Q^2}\right)}}-{2ab}}\over{6a}}$

Comment: Thanks @SenexÆgyptiParvi, added to the answer.